# Bash: ssh with host name as variable

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

It's my first bash program and I have troubles logging into ssh with variables.
Currently it looks like this

```
servername="my_pc"
ssh user@$servername "./test.sh"
```

But I get the error Could not resolve hostname : name or service not known

If I directly write

```
ssh user@my_pc "./test.sh"
```

it works

```
servername="user@my_pc"
ssh $servername "./test.sh"
```

also works.

I need to use variables because I want to ssh into multiple servers and so the variable changes in the future.

Comment: Make sure your script file does **not** have DOS-style `\r\n` line endings -- check your editor's settings. If you do, then ssh thinks the hostname is `my_pc\r`. You can check with `cat -A script.sh` and look for `^M$` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message normally contains the hostname, as in

```
$ ssh user@xyz
Could not resolve hostname xyz: Name or service not known
```

So I guess you misspelled the variable name in your actual command.

You can run your script under

```
set -u
```

which will cause the script to fail when an undefined variable is used. Similarly, using `set -e` would end the script when any error is encountered.